# Dict Comprehension using isinstance for float and int key values

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary with floats and int values, I'm trying to use dict comprehension to encode both. How can I incorporate an isinstance(attempts.params[i], float) and isinstance(attempts.params[i], int) so I can get the correct values?

attempts.params is a list:

```
[name: "p1"
float_value: 0.93712629656
, name: "p2"
int_value: 7
, name: "p3"
float_value: 0.293585904040
, name: "p4"
int_value: 6
, name: "p5"
int_value: 7]





{attempts.params[i].name.encode('ascii','ignore'):attempts.params[i].float_value for i in range(len(attempts.params))}
```

Output:

```
{'p1': 0.93712629656,
'p2': 0.0,
'p3': 0.293585904040,
'p4': 0.0,
'p5': 0.0}
```

As you can see p2, p4, and p5 are int values so they aren't coming out correctly.

I tried:

```
{attempts.params[i].name.encode('ascii','ignore'):attempts.params[i].float_value for i in range(len(attempts.params)) if isinstance(attempts.params[i], float)}
```

but got an empty dict {}

Desired Output:

```
{'p1': 0.93712629656,
'p2': 7,
'p3': 0.293585904040,
'p4': 10,
'p5': 5}
```

Comment: Outputs fine, but where is the input?

Comment: What exactly *is* `attempts.params[i]`? It's not an `int` *or* a `float` if it has `int_value` and/or `float_value` attributes.

Comment: What about a modulo 1 check? `if x % 1 == 0` means you have an `int`.

Comment: Perhaps something like `{x.name.encode('ascii', 'ignore'): x.float_value if hasattr(x, 'float_value') else x.int_value for x in attempts.params}`.

Comment: You "list" isn't a valid Python expression.

Answer (score 1):

`attempts.params[i]` isn't an `int` *or* a `float`, based the attributes it has. Instead, it might have an `int`-valued attribute or a `float`-valued attribute; `isinstance` won't tell you which.

Instead, just try to get the value of `int_value`; if that fails, get the value of `float_value`; and if *that* fails, just use `None`.

Also, don't iterate over the assumed indices of `attempts.params`; just iterate over the items themselves.

```
{x.name.encode('ascii', 'ignore'): 
   getattr(x, 
           'int_value',
           getattr(x,
                   'float_value',
                    None))
   for x in attempts.params}
```

Comment: I'm getting this:
{'p1': 0L,
 'p2': 7L,
 'p3': 0L,
 'p4': 6L,
 'p5': 7L}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed version of your list (I'll update my answer if you update your input):

```
params = [
    {"name": "p1", "float_value": 0.93712629656},
    {"name": "p2", "int_value": 7},
    {"name": "p3", "float_value": 0.293585904040},
    {"name": "p4", "int_value": 6},
    {"name": "p5", "int_value": 7}
]
```

To extract the value from a param, you have to test the existence of the `float_value` key in the dict:

```
def get_value(param): 
    return param["float_value"] if "float_value" in param else param["int_value"]
```

Now:

```
print({param["name"].encode('ascii','ignore'): get_value(param) for param in params})
```

Has the expected output:

```
{b'p1': 0.93712629656, b'p2': 7, b'p3': 0.29358590404, b'p4': 6, b'p5': 7}
```